# SerialPort Thread on Windows

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.6, pyserial

I need the give SerialConnection object to ThreadClass how can I do that?

I faced an error on Windows OS. But same code have not any error in Linux (Ubuntu).

I create the SerialConnection() object in MainWindow also self.angleThread created same init function.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # self = QMainWindow class
        # self.ui = Ui_MainWindow / user interface class
        loadJsonStyle(self, self.ui)
        QSizeGrip(self.ui.size_grip)
        self.connection = SerialConnection()
        self.Rs232 = RS232_Data()
        self.angleThread = ThreadClass("filename", index)
```

I need the serial connection in ThreadClass so  both function calling in ThreadClass init.

```
   def __init__(self,  filename = "", index = 0):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__()
        self.filename = filename
        self.is_running = True
        self.index = index
        # self.connection.close
        self.Rs232 = RS232_Data()
        self.connection = SerialConnection()
        ...
```

SerialConnection class:

```
class SerialConnection():
    def __init__(self):
        portList = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
        self.serialPort = 0
        for p in portList:
            # print(p.pid)
            if p.pid == 24577:
                print("Confirmed")
                self.getPortName = p.device
                self.serialPort = serial.Serial(port=self.getPortName, baudrate=230400, bytesize=8, timeout=10, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

                break
            else:
                ## Show dialog
                print("There is no device on the line")
    def connection_start(self):
        try:
            # self.serialPort.open()
            1 == 1
        except Exception:
            print("Port is already open")
    def connection_close(self):
        if self.serialPort.is_open:
            self.serialPort.close()
        else:
            print("Port didnt open")
    def serial_write(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.serialPort.write(self.data)
    def serial_read_string(self):

        readData = self.serialPort.readline()
        return readData
    def serial_read_byte(self,size):
        readData = self.serialPort.read(size)
        # print(len(readData))
        if len(readData) == 0:
            print("unconnceted")
        return readData
```

But In the windows I get below error:

```
    raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM12': PermissionError(13, 'Erişim engellendi.', None, 5)
```

How can I solve this problem or how can I move the alive connection to ThreadClass ?

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you opening the same port twice?
Once in MainWindow constructor and later second time in ThreadClass constructor.
As far as I know this is forbidden in Windows.

You can just pass SerialConnection instance as a ThreadClass constructor parameter instead of creating it there.

Comment: How can I do this "You can just pass SerialConnection instance as a ThreadClass constructor parameter instead of creating it there." @Zuljin

Comment: If I create the serial connection in ThreadClass how can I access this connection in another class ? Without initilize ThreadClass Again because threadclass have another process

Comment: Is ThreadClass a different thread or process? Base on name I assumed it is a different thread. You haven't showed whole code of ThreadClass so I don't know. 
With different thread you can just pass an instance of class SerialConnection() in the same way as you do filename and index parameter.
It fis is different process then you have to close serial port in MainWindow class before creating ThreadClass